# Snap scroll CSS too fast/jumpy in Chrome but works fine everywhere else

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll-snap

Very new to this but I have a page of sections that I have a scroll snap function, but when viewed on chrome the transition isn't smooth at all, it jumps from one section to the other far too quickly.
Is there any way to solve this??

https://www.matthewjameswilson.com/

This is the code I am using:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth Scrolling in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543484/smooth-scrolling-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

you have missed to add an smooth attribute `scroll-behavior: smooth;` on CSS

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: added the ```scroll-behavior: smooth ``` but no change when viewed on Chrome. Especially bad with mouse scroll, not too bad with touch pad. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: can you put your code into codepen. so I can check and update the answer

Comment: Did you get the outcome? scroll-behavior: smooth is not smooth as I want, can I adjust scroll time?

Comment: yes which works perferctly

Answer (score 0):

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

Fixes only when scrolling by clicking an `<a>` tag. An issue is getting that smooth scroll when scrolling with the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

For someone still find the answer for this issue.
I disabled scroll with mouse wheel and trigger a normal scroll event.
Mouse wheel has weird behavior with `scroll-snap` CSS

```js
const scrollYPerView = parent.clientHeight;
parent.addEventListener('wheel', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    scrollDown();
  } else {
    scrollUp();
  }
});

function scrollUp() {
  let currentScrollY = parent.scrollTop;
  parent.scroll({top: currentScrollY - scrollYPerView, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}

function scrollDown() {
  let currentScrollY = parent.scrollTop;
  parent.scroll({top: currentScrollY + scrollYPerView, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It scrolls when mouse wheel event `(deltaY = 100 or -100)` is detected. Use `scrollBy` to add `deltaY` to current position.

```
element.addEventListener("wheel", function (event) {
    if ((event.deltaY === 100) || (event.deltaY === -100)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        element.scrollBy({
            top: event.deltaY,
            behavior: "smooth",
        });
    }
});
```